# How to link each UITableViewCell with another view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, view, cell

I'm new in iOS programming, and I want to do a simple thing. I saw several topics about my problem, but I don't understand why my code doesn't work...

- I created an empty view called *details.xib*
- I created an objective-C class, so I have two empty files *details.h* and *details.m*
- In my main view called *ViewController.xib*, I have a tableView
- In *ViewController.m*, I added  on the top : `#import "details.h"`
- In *ViewController.m*, I modified the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method like this :

  ```
  details *det = [[details alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:det animated:YES];
  ```

I obtain this avertissement : **Incomptatible pointer types sending 'details *__strong' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'**

Sorry if my english is awkward, I'm french... Thanks for your help !

Comment: details is a UIView or a UIViewController?

Comment: det use as a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you are rooted the details.xib with class properly in file owner.

Refer this image:

[image]

And make sure you Details view controller is a sub class of UIViewController if not, create a view controller as UIViewController sub class(While creating a view controller itself u will can choose. refer below image)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure detail view is a sub class of UIViewcontroller?

Comment: Your details.h  @interface details : UIViewController  resembles this line exactly?

Comment: I created a new class called details2ViewController with the wizard, to be sure. But it changes nothing...

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSMutableArray *MenuArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 //Populate your array dynamically. Here I have populate my array with a custom object
 [MenuArray addObject:[[GlobalMethod alloc] initWithMenuName:@"Home" WithNibNumber:1]];
 [MenuArray addObject:[[GlobalMethod alloc] initWithMenuName:@"Profile" WithNibNumber:2]];
 [MenuArray addObject:[[GlobalMethod alloc] initWithMenuName:@"Friends" WithNibNumber:3]];
 [MenuArray addObject:[[GlobalMethod alloc] initWithMenuName:@"Photos" WithNibNumber:4]];

 // And so on.....


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [MenuArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   GlobalMethod *Method=[MenuArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
   UITableViewCell *cell;
   [cell setTag:[Method NibNumber]];
   return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   if([cell tag]==1)
   {
      //push to viewController1
   }
   else if([cell tag]==2)
   {
      //push to  viewController12
   }
   else
   {
      //and go on
   }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that because my TableView is dynamically filled.

Comment: check my updated answer. I hope you can understood what you have to do

Comment: can you show me your code... I mean what you have tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

Compiler is telling you : "I'm expecting some `UIViewController` subclass in this `presentViewController:animated:` method, and it's NOT"

`detail` should indeed be a `detailViewController`, subclassing `UIViewController`.

**EDIT**

Go to your `detail` class header files (detail.h), make sure it inherits from **UIViewController** :

```
@interface detail : UIViewController

//properties & methods declarations...

@end
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but how can I do that ? Sorry, I'm not at-ease with iOS yet...

Comment: Then maybe you should spend some more time doing tutorials before rushing on stackoverflow... I edited my answer to make it more explicit :)

Comment: So you shouldn't have the warning **Incomptatible pointer types sending 'details *__strong' to parameter of type 'UIViewController *'**, do you ?

Comment: Then something happens here `[self.navigationController pushViewController:det animated:YES];`, make sure your `ViewController` is indeed embedded in a `UINavigationController`, if not, you can see it in the debugger : self.navigationController will be nil.

Comment: Indeed, self.navigationController value is null. So I have to neccessary add a UINavigationController in my details2ViewController.xib ?

Comment: It depends on how your viewController are instantiated : from storyboard ? or programamtically form UIApplicationDelegate ? Please make another question, and mark this one - related to the pointer warning - as solved

Comment: Please go here for the continuation : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961798/make-a-link-for-each-uitableviewcell-with-another-view)