# Make a link for each UITableViewCell with another view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, view, cell

I'm new in iOS programming, and I want to do a simple thing. I saw several topics about my problem, but I don't understand why my code doesn't work...

- I created a UIViewController subclass called details2ViewController, with a .xib
- In my main view called *ViewController.xib*, I have a tableView
- In *ViewController.m*, I added  on the top : `#import "details2ViewController.h"`
- In *ViewController.m*, I modified the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method like this :

  ```
  details *det = [[details alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:det animated:YES];
  ```

There is no warning, but no effect when I click on a cell... I precise that I'm working without mainStoryBoard.

*note : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959129/how-to-link-each-uitableviewcell-with-another-view)'s my previously post about this problem.*

(Sorry if my english is awkward, I'm french... Thanks for your help !)

Comment: Did you assign the tableview's delegate to your file owner of `ViewController` ?

Comment: Is your ViewController embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: @rdelmar No, but it's really necessary ? If yes, i have to do that in Interface Builder ? (create a navigationController and push my viewController into it ?) I'm not very good in iOS/XCode yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all check that you have properly wired your TableView's delegate to your ViewController's File Owner or not. TableView's `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is a delegate method.

Secondly, I am not getting why are using `details` as a Class name when you already have imported `details2ViewController.h`. So, It looks like you should use `details2ViewController` instead `details` and your code should look like this :

```
 details2ViewController *det = [[details2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"details2ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:det animated:YES];
```

---

Make sure that your `ViewController` is indeed embedded in a `UINavigationController`. If not then your `self.navigationController will` be `nil`.

Or you can go through [An Introduction To UINavigationController](http://simplecode.me/2011/09/04/an-introduction-to-uinavigationcontroller/).

Comment: Yes, there linked.
Yes, please forget _"details"_, I create a new one, that called "_details2ViewController"_.
I tried your code, but when I do that :
_details2ViewController *det = [[details2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"details2ViewController"];_ I get a warning **No visible @interface for 'details2ViewController' declares the selector 'initWithNibName'** .

So i does that :
_details2ViewController *det = [[details2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"details2ViewController" bundle:nil];_ no warning, but not work

Comment: @Erzékiel : I have added one Link in my Answer. Check it. It has a step by step guide with tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Storyboard you can use this code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
YourViewController *yourViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBoardID"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Don't forget to set `animated:BOOL` to `YES` in last line.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to do that without using Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first define a property of navigation controller in your AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *controller;
```

Then in the AppDelegate.m file do this in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method :

```
details2ViewController *controller=[[details2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"details2ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
}

self.window.rootViewController=self.controller;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Then in the details2ViewController.m in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
details2ViewController *det = [[details2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"details2ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:det animated:YES];
```

Do let me know if it work.. :) Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's the same method that the one I found following the link into the Vin's answer. But thank you too !